# Url path not changing when using $location.path in angular js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Url path not changing when using `$location.path` in angular js when checking with if condition. 
I'm posting my below snippet for reference.

**App.js** :

```
.state('home.selectCart',{
          url:'/cart_selection',
          views: {
              content: {
                  template: '',
                  controller: 'SelectCartCtrl'
              }
          },
          authenticate: true
        })
```

**Controller.js** :

```
.controller('SelectCartCtrl', [ '$scope' ,'ProductFactory', '$location', function($scope,ProductFactory, $location){

      $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var cartType = ProductFactory.getCartType();
        if(cartType == 'b2b') {
           $location.path('/home/b2b/cart');
        }
        if(cartType == 'b2c'){
          $location.path('/home/cart');
        }
      });
}])
```

And, in my html file I'm using `href="#/home/cart_selection"` for tab selection:

Comment: no.. i'm new to angularjs. could you pls help?

Comment: im getting this error : Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: and try using, location.hash instead of location.path